# displaying markers on google map from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-markers

I have lng/lat values stored in mysql and trying to display them on a google map...

```
 <?php  
    require ('db_info.php');
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

    ?>

    <html lang="en">
    {% include 'components/head.html' %}

    <body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
    {% include 'components/nav-account.html' %}
    <div id = "page-wrapper">
    {% include 'components/alerts.html' %}

    <div class = "container">
    <style type = "text/css">
    html, body, #map-canvas{ height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type = "text/javascript"
    src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
                            key=AIzaSyB76xBqfQdgOLV77VK3JZ09vWwk8brkMFs">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addMarker(lat, lng){
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pt,
            map: map
        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: -6.284874},
            zoom: 15
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);         
  } 

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("select * from tester") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $lat = $row['lat'];
            $lng = $row['lng'];           
            echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng)");       
        }
    ?>


    </script>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:600px; width:600px;
         margin-top:100px; margin-bottom: 100px;
         ">

    </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'components/footer.html' %}    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Currently the map is not showing up at all, but it was before I was trying to retrieve information from the database.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try adding another semicolon here? `echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng);");`

Comment: @Don'tPanic - NIce spot, but unfortunately still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the addMarker call to inside the initialize function.
Before the initialize call is made, there is no map thus no way to add a marker.

I did not check your code for syntax.
you also need a global javascript variable called map...
var map = null;
This needs to be outside the initialize call, then ditch the var map inside and instead just use map =

```
 <?php  
    require ('db_info.php');
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

    ?>

    <html lang="en">
    {% include 'components/head.html' %}

    <body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
    {% include 'components/nav-account.html' %}
    <div id = "page-wrapper">
    {% include 'components/alerts.html' %}

    <div class = "container">
    <style type = "text/css">
    html, body, #map-canvas{ height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type = "text/javascript"
    src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
                            key=AIzaSyB76xBqfQdgOLV77VK3JZ09vWwk8brkMFs">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;

    function addMarker(lat, lng){
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pt,
            map: map
        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: -6.284874},
            zoom: 15
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);         

    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("select * from tester") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $lat = $row['lat'];
            $lng = $row['lng'];           
            echo "addMarker($lat, $lng);";       
        }
    ?>
  } 

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:600px; width:600px;
         margin-top:100px; margin-bottom: 100px;
         ">

    </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'components/footer.html' %}    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Cheers - however still not working, so maybe a syntax problem?! I'll check through that and my database information as well.

Comment: is my problem possibly that I'm using php within a javascript function?

Comment: Nope... remember that PHP pushes text to the browser... so you can write javascript wherever you want. the browser then executes the javascript once it receives all of the page (which is produced by php)... I didn't see any obvious syntax problem.... but it would be helpful if you could describe what exactly you see.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks.  I am my header, navbar and footer, but nothing else. With the php part removed from initialize I can see my map, but obviously with no markers!

Comment: So there is likely a problem with your php code... you should check your web server logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: getting SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' at the start of the php in initialie()...

Comment: ah, you are mixing TWIG and php... twig doesnt execute php code the same way. you will need to lookup the proper twig syntax